# pass an array of api keys to a const in react native

Tags: react-native

This api returns an array of 20 items, I would like to use/pass two keys to a function.

```
  [
  {  0      
    close:  172.26
    label:  "Jan 2"
     },
  {
    close:  172.23
    label:  "Jan 3"
...
```

My goal is to generate a graph chart, the library require some data in that format:

```
const data = [
    [{
      "x": 0,
      "y": 123
    }, {
      "x": 1,
      "y": 456
    }, {
      "x": 2,
      "y": 789
    }],
  ];
```

I have to dynamically generate those x and y by replacing them with api results, how can I achieve that?

Comment: have you tried anything? please add code

Comment: @shahzad-mirza maybe you can help me google something

Comment: @svddxnly, which chart library are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Solution to your problem:

```js
const data = [
    [{
        close: 172.26,
        label: "Jan 2"
    }, {
        close: 172.23,
        label: "Jan 3"
    }]
];


data[0] = data[0].map(item => {
    const { close: y, label: x } = { ...item }
    return { x, y }
});

console.log(data)
```

and in `react-native` you can do the following:-

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: [
        [{
          close: 172.26,
          label: "Jan 2"
        },
        {
          close: 172.23,
          label: "Jan 3"
        }]
      ]
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    let { data } = this.state;
    data[0] = data[0].map(item => {
      const { close: y, label: x } = { ...item }
      return { x, y }
    });
    this.setState({ data }); 
  }
```

I hope it will help you.